# Handle a 500 response with the fetch api

Tags: typescript, fetch, aurelia

We have the following call to `fetch`.

```
this.http.fetch('flasher', { method: 'post', body: jsonPayload })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

This works when we receive a 200 response but logs nothing to the console when we receive a 500 response. How do we handle a 500?

Comment: i'm not familiar at all with the framework or the fetch api, but i found this: https://gist.github.com/bryanrsmith/14caed2015b9c54e70c3; fetch().then().catch(unk => conole.log(unk));

Comment: Nice research. That is also shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch Thank you.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

## Working Solution

Combining `then` with `catch` works.

```
fetch('http://some-site.com/api/some.json')  
  .then(function(response) {                      // first then()
      if(response.ok)
      {
        return response.text();         
      }

      throw new Error('Something went wrong.');
  })  
  .then(function(text) {                          // second then()
    console.log('Request successful', text);  
  })  
  .catch(function(error) {                        // catch
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  });
```

## Details

`fetch()` returns a `Promise` containing a `Response` object. The `Promise` can become either fulfilled or rejected. Fulfillment runs the first `then()`, returns its promise, and runs the second `then()`. Rejection throws on the first `then()` and jumps to the `catch()`.

## References

[MDN - Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[MDN - Checking that the fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

[Google - Introduction to Fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to wrap in an object like `console.log({data})`