# net::ERR_ABORTED 500 when using fetch POST to web

Tags: javascript, http, post, httprequest, fetch

I have a piece of code that makes a post request to another website (minehut API)

```js
    <script>
      fetch("https://api.minehut.com/users/login", {  
        mode: "no-cors",
        method: 'POST',  
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json"
        },  
         body: {
           "email":"no no no",
           "password": "no no no"
        }
      })
      .then(function (data) {  
        console.log('Request success: ', data);  
      })  
      .catch(function (error) {  
        console.log('Request failure: ', error);  
      });
```

however when i run it it returns `net::ERR_ABORTED 500` and doesnt give a response.

How do i prevent it from showing this error and get a response.

Comment: the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225862/handle-a-500-response-with-the-fetch-api Try to catch error status in `.then()` adding `if (response.status >= 500) { // do your logic }`

Comment: the problem is that i dont want to handle the error, i want to prevent it @Serj

Comment: error code generated by the server you can`t change this